# Graph Api to send message to a non-friend on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to send a message automatically with the Facebook Graph API to a Facebook user who is not a friend or user of the authorized application?

I know that we couldn't before. 
but is there a method today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SHORT Answer**

> No you can't

**Long Answer**

**If** the conversation is between two Facebook Users :

> No you can't use Graph API, because you won't get the mailbox permissions.

**If** you don't need to use the GRAPH API, consider the **SEND Dialog**, then it should be possible

> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

**If** the conversation is between a Facebook Page and a Facebook User

> You can send only a message if the Facebook User initiated at first the chat with the Facebook Page.

**As you noticed, none of these meet your Use case** :)

I hope this answers your concern

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

Do You know if we can post on a wall ? To a non-friend user.

Comment: Users can only post to a Friend's wall via the Share/Send dialogue. So no :)